# jplayer not playing mp3 in some ie and chrome browsers

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mp3, icecast

Some machines can't seem to play (or are extremely delayed) mp3 files fed to jPlayer from IceCast2.

Browsers in question: Chrome 49 / 50, IE 11

It works fine on about 75% of the computers / tablets / phones tested (including many browsers not listed in the question).

One thing to note, if it will not play on one browser, it will not play on any browser on the machine in questions.  The one exception to this rule, a machine that could not play updated their IE from 9 to 11 and it worked on IE, but would not work on Chrome before or after the upgrade.

I am guessing that some application / web app / pluggin has been installed on these machines (iTunes, Pandora, etc) that is blocking the jPlayer code from working.

Using devtools, you can watch the browser try to load the audio but it just stalls out either forever, or for a very long time (up to 25 minutes in some cases).

Has anyone dealt with a similar situation and if so, how did you solve the problem?  Many hours of googling have been burned to answer this question with no result...

The relevant code from IceCast2:

```
<limits>
    <clients>1000</clients>
    <sources>5</sources>
    <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
    <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
    <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
    <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
    <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
    <burst-size>4096</burst-size>
</limits>

<listen-socket>
    <port>9600</port>
</listen-socket>

<mount type="normal">
    <mount-name>/Meeting</mount-name>
    <max-listeners>100</max-listeners>
    <public>1</public>
    <stream-url>http://www.taneycounty.org/lld.php</stream-url>
    <bitrate>64</bitrate>
    <type>application/mp3</type>
    <hidden>1</hidden>
    <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
    <mp3-metadata-interval>4096</mp3-metadata-interval>
</mount>
```

The relevant browser code from jPlayer:

```
<audio
  controls id="tc-audio-element"
  autoplay="autoplay"
  src="http://www.taneycounty.org:9600/Meeting?rand=f3rqw63kt74zghcn&type=.mp3"
  type="audio/mp3" >
  <source
    src="http://www.taneycounty.org:9600/Meeting?rand=f3rqw63kt74zghcn&type=.mp3"
    type="audio/mp3" >
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Is there some sort of IDS or firewall between that machine and the Internet? I can't reach it from one location, while it works fine from others. Traceroute stops at the last hop before the machine itself.

Comment: It is not currently running.  It is for live meetings only.  I can setup a looped demo, but I will need to change some of the code as the original listed was the production code...

Comment: The Icecast server itself is running. I can reach it from other locations. But from one ISP the IP of your server can't be reached at all.

Comment: Well, there is definitely our firewall that you would have to go through.  I am not sure what IP you are having issues with, but at the moment, I can't even get into the firewall to look.  Long story, but my main work PC is dead and I am having to fight the uphill battle of Java to get Cisco's software to work.  As soon as I have it, I can turn a test on so you can have a more in-depth look.  Sorry for the delay.  I had forgotten what a nightmare Cisco + Java is with all their "security" hurdles to go through...

Comment: No one can help you if there is no way to experience the problem in action. Maybe just setup that looped demo & turn it off when you have a real meeting. Also an installed OS application would not interfere with javascript  or the HTML5 audio tag as used on web pages. I would check the net connection of the failing machines (any data restrictions blocking A/V media files?, a slower net that is busy with another download or auto-update that is hogging the line?). Whatever case, if it works for others then the problem is not the stream or server but with the connecting clients, examine those...

Answer (score -1):

What do your logs show when the uses have attempted to connect In the past? Relevant logs, with a working demo wild help immensely. Good luck.